# SharedPreferences Long value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here I'm creating a `SharedPreferences` if I'm not wrong i'm using this code :

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putLong("ExactTime", minutesToMilliseconds(NumberPicker2.getValue()));
editor.commit();
```

What I'm doing is I get a `value` from a `NumberPicker` and I want to save this `value` and once an user restart the APP or even reboot the device (I don't know if `SharedPreferences` does it...) when the user opens the APP it still the same number picked from `NumberPicker`.

And I want to use this in a **class that extends a `Service`**. What I've tried is :

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("ExactTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
WifiTimeSearch = sp.getLong("ExactTime", 0);
```

Here is where I'm lost... I've read that this "0" means a default value but I want to use the same value that I've stored on `SharedPreferences`... And when I try to use this `Long` value, the value is "0".

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reading and writing to different SharedPreference files.

Also, by using `getPreferences()`, you're writing to SharedPreferences that are local to that Activity.

From the source code:

```
/**
     * Retrieve a {@link SharedPreferences} object for accessing preferences
     * that are private to this activity.  This simply calls the underlying
     * {@link #getSharedPreferences(String, int)} method by passing in this activity's
     * class name as the preferences name.
     *
     * @param mode Operating mode.  Use {@link #MODE_PRIVATE} for the default
     *             operation, {@link #MODE_WORLD_READABLE} and
     *             {@link #MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE} to control permissions.
     *
     * @return Returns the single SharedPreferences instance that can be used
     *         to retrieve and modify the preference values.
     */
    public SharedPreferences getPreferences(int mode) {
        return getSharedPreferences(getLocalClassName(), mode);
    }
```

To make it work, just use the default SharedPreferences for your app:

Writing:

```
    SharedPreferences sp =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putLong("ExactTime", minutesToMilliseconds(NumberPicker2.getValue()));
    editor.commit();
```

Reading:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    WifiTimeSearch = sp.getLong("ExactTime", 0);
```

Note that as long as you are in an Activity or a Service, you can use `this` as the Context.

Comment: Worked like a charm Daniel, thanks a lot :) I was missing `PreferenceManager`.

Answer (score 2):

In SharedPreferences, The first parameter is the key and the second parameter is the MODE. So to `COMMIT` as well as to `retrieve` value we have to use same key.

try this code to commit :

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ExactTime",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putLong("ExactTime", minutesToMilliseconds(NumberPicker2.getValue()));
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess problem is you are passing preference file name as "**ExactTime**" while reading from preferences, while saving you are not specifying any

Try this

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(null,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
WifiTimeSearch = sp.getLong("ExactTime", 0);
```

Comment: getSharedPreferences() requires a `String` and an `int` if I'm not wrong... Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: you can pass null as first parameter.. editted my answer

Comment: @Akhil But while retrieving value he is using key "ExactTime" then does it work?

Comment: Also while writing you can pass null as first parameter